# UIImageView rotate

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Привет!

Пытаюсь сделать вращение UIImageView.

В viewDidLoad создаю картинку.

```
UIImage *radarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newRadar.png"];
myRadarImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 80, 250, 250)];
myRadarImage.image = radarImage;
[self.myView addSubview:myRadarImage]; // Добавляю в myView - subview от self.view
myRadarImage.center = self.view.center;
[self goRotate];
```

И сам метод вращения:

```
- (void)goRotate {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:4.0f];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    myRadarImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((180.0f * M_PI) / 180.0f);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Проблема в том, что анимация происходит мгновенно, а не за 4 секунды. Хотя если создать чистый проект - то все нормально работает.
Пробовал [myRadarImage setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вызвать `[self goRotate];` в методе viewDidAppear

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self goRotate];
{
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 2):

Вызывайте анимацию в `wiewDidAppear`

и перепишите метод анимации

```
- (void)goRotate {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4.f
                     animations:^{
                     myRadarImage.transform = 
                              CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((180.0f * M_PI) / 180.0f);
                 }];
}
```

или более крутая анимация под iOS 7 с bounce эффектом (коэффициенты надо подбирать)

```
- (void)goRotate {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4.f
                          delay:0
         usingSpringWithDamping:0.8f
          initialSpringVelocity:0.5f
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^ {
                         myRadarImage.transform = 
                              CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((180.0f * M_PI) / 180.0f);
                     } completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: спасибо ребята! всегда выручаете:)